# How to change color of only one stack in ggplot stacked barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, plotly

I have a ggplot stacked barplot like below

[image]

I want to change the color combination of stacks only for `dec` , for example c("red", "green"). My desired output is

[image: desired_plot]

I tried

```
ggplot() +    
geom_bar(data = x1, aes(y = values, x = months, fill = variable), stat="identity") +   
scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "blue")) +       
geom_bar(data = x2, aes(y = values, x = months, fill = variable), stat="identity") +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green"))
```

It takes only the last `scale_fill_manual` values.
If it was a regular barplot, changing `fill` in `geom_bar` works. I can't figure out how to do this for stacked plot without creating extra values for legend.

In my code, x1 contains values for jan to nov and x2 contains values for dec. Both are subsets of whole data.

Comment: What is the question? For me, looks like you achieved what you wanted?

Comment: No, the second plot shows the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give the code without the dataset, but what you want to try to do is create a new `type` column (for the full data set) that will distinguish between the Dec column and the other ones, so you'll have four types: chickens, eggs, chickens-December, eggs-December. `fill` based on this new column, and you'll get new colours for the December bars.

You can then use

```
scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("chickens","eggs"),
                values=c("green", "orange", "red", "blue"))
```

to only include those values you want in the legend (pardon my random colour choice - use better ones for your graph).